# How to add markers to leaflet map in an ajax call? leaflet Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addLayer') Layer.js:52

Tags: django, ajax, leaflet

I am trying to add markers to my leaflet map in an ajax call, but I am getting an error. I'm able to add markers to the map in the console, but don't know why I can't in the ajax call. Any help would be appreciated.

**Ajax Call**

```
// get reference to map
var map = window['leafletmapid_location-map'];
$('#id_sub_areas').change(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'my_url',
        success: function (response) {
            L.marker([40.383061, -111.773658]).addTo(map)
        };
    });
});
```

When I trigger the ajax call I get the error message- **leaflet Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addLayer') Layer.js:52**

However if I load the page I can add a marker to the map with the following code in the console.

**Console Code**

```
var map = window['leafletmapid_location-map'];
L.marker([40.383061, -111.773658]).addTo(map);
```

Comment: What do you have if you `console.log(map)` just before creating the Marker?

Comment: @ghybs undefined. Even if I place console.log(map) immediately after declaring the map variable completely outside of my ajax call I still get undefined.